# My family saw small dots in the sky moving rapidly at night

Tags: observational-astronomy

My family and I saw small dots moving rapidly from north to south that flew in a V formation (the kind that ducks fly in). There aren't any ducks in my country. This phenomenon appeared twice. They're not stars or satellites. Could they be any type of UFO?

Comment: Please see the other questions about "moving lights in the sky", then consider if your question has sufficicent detail to be be answered.

Comment: No my question is different I'm not taking about star I'm taking about small dots

Comment: Fast, dim, North to South are usually US spy satellites.

Comment: Mahendra, the other question provides *excellent* answers covering just about any question about a *light moving in the sky*. Please read the answers carefully.

Comment: *not any type of ufo* If you don't know what it and it's apparently in the sky is then by *definition* it's a ufo.  Unidentified Flying Object.  It remains a ufo until it is identified.

Comment: Just because ducks don't live in your country doesn't mean they couldn't fly over. Some birds migrate across half the planet each year, yet never really 'live' in the places in between. If this was early evening you may have seen some pale birds flying very high up, still catching the light from the sun even though from your point of view it had set.